# AOSP: Disable default display

Tags: android, android-source, display, q

I'm  trying to disable the default/built in display in AOSP. Is there a default flag i can enable/disable to achieve this?. Note: I am compiling Android 10.

I suspect his is possible because of a comment in [/core/java/android/view/Display.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/23cca12865549bc6d34f0842f6469fef7b9f944b/core/java/android/view/Display.java#L115)
I tried removing the `builtin` or `internal` flags in `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/display/LocalDisplayAdapter.java` but that causes `DisplayManagerService` to throw an exception `onBootPhase`. Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround only since i couldn't find the actual place to disable it but this worked.
In [DisplayManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.java) on the `public Display[] getDisplays(String category)` method i checked. If there's two displays, then ignore whatever display is not the default display. Terrible temporary workaround but this is my solution. Accepting until someone posts a better soltuion!